# Install emerald font package on ubuntu

Tags: fonts, installing, debugging

I tried to install the emerald font package on my ubuntu natty box. However if I compile a minimal example like (`emerald.tex`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}
\ECFTeenSpirit
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

I get the following error

```
Running `LaTeX' on `emerald' with ``pdflatex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" emerald.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, nohyphenation, ngerman, german, german-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ibycus, monogreek, greek, ancientgreek, loaded.
(./emerald.tex (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/home/myuser/texmf/tex/latex/emerald/emerald.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)) (./emerald.aux)
(/home/myuser/texmf/tex/latex/emerald/t1fts.fd) [1{/home/myuser/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./emerald.aux) ) </home/myuser/.texmf-var/
fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm1000.600pk>
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ftsmdw8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ftsmdw8r.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

A `locate ftsmdw8r` gives me `/home/myuser/texmf/fonts/tfm/emerald/ftsmdw8r.tfm`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here are the steps I did for the installation:

```
cd ~/texmf
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/emerald.zip
unzip emerald.zip
cd emerald 
cp -r tex/* ../tex/
cp -r fonts/* ../fonts/    
texhash $HOME/texmf
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=emerald.map
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've tried it with TeXlive 2012, and got it working with the following steps:

```
mkdir -p `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME`
cd `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME`
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/emerald.zip
unzip emerald.zip
cp -r emerald/. . && rm -rf emerald/
rm emerald.zip
updmap --enable Map emerald.map
texhash
```

If this doesn't work, there might be issues in creating the updmap config, try:

```
mkdir -p ~/.texmf-config/web2c
echo Map emerald.map >> ~/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap
```

Also check the `emerald.map` file can actually be found:

```
kpsewhich emerald.map
```

Comment: I could not install this unit in my Ubuntu.

Comment: It works on my Mac OSX with MacTex installed as well. First, download the `emerald` zip file from ctan and unzip it. Second, copy the two dirs: `fonts` and `tex` to `~/Library/texmf/`. Third, run the two command `updmap` and `texhash` as mentioned by @Silex.

Comment: Worked fine (on Ubuntu 13.04 and manually installed TeXLive); did have to `sudo texhash`, though. (In fact, `sudo \`which texhash\`` because TeXLive is not in root's PATH on my machine.)

Comment: Still working like a charm (August 2014).

Comment: Still working amazingly (January 2018)

Comment: I completely understood nothing about the procedure... @Silke can you kidly suggest me some resources for understanding the procedure in case I get a similar problem?

Comment: @ErikPillon The steps are covered here: https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall-personal.html
That page also links to the system-wide installation instructions, which contain more detail.